# Picard group of a very ample divisor in a smooth variety of dimension >3

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety, $\dim(X)>3$ and $D$ be a very ample possibly reducible divisor on $X$. Is it true that $\textrm{Pic}(X)\cong \textrm{Pic}(D)$? If not, what would be a reasonable condition on $D$ (for example, would it suffice that $D$ is irreducible)?

(if you have a precise reference, I would be especially grateful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **yes** under very mild assumptions. In fact there is the following result.

> **Proposition.** Let $L$ be a $k$-ample line bundle on a normal, irreducible, projective variety $X$ with at most Cohen-Macauley singularities. Assume that the dimension of the locus of non-rational singularities of $X$ is at most $0$ and that $D \in |L|$ is a divisor such that $X-D$ is a local complete intersection. Then, under the restriction mapping, we have $\textrm{Pic}(X) \cong \textrm{Pic}(D)$ if $\dim X \geq 4+k$ and $\textrm{Pic}(X) \to \textrm{Pic}(D)$ is injective with torsion free cokernel if $\dim X = 3+k$.

The case you are interested in corresponds to $k=0$. For instance, if $X$ is smooth (of dimension at least $4$) then all the assumptions are fulfilled and what you want is true.

The Proposition above is a consequence of Hamm's Lefschetz Theorem. For further details, see  Beltrametti-Sommese, *The adjunction theory of complex projective varieties*, Corollary 2.3.4 page 51.

**Remark.**  Given an integer $k \geq 0$, a line bundle $L$ on a projective variety $X$ is said to be $k$-ample if $a L$ is spanned for some $a > 0$, and the morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^{h^0(aL)-1}$ defined by $|a L|$ has all fibers of dimension $\leq k$. For $k=0$, this is one of the basic characterization of ampleness.

Comment: Dear Francesco, thank you, this is very helpful!

Comment: Francesco, could you please tell me the definition of a $k$-ample bundle (I realised I can not find in it...)? 

Comment: You are welcome. I added in the answer a remark explaining the meaning of $k$-ampleness.

Answer (score 2):

Francesco Polizzi's answer is perfectly correct; also there are generalizations in the second part of *Stratified Morse Theory* by Goresky-MacPherson.  However I want to point out that there is a different, much more algebraic perspective that works over an arbitrary field developed in *SGA 2. Cohomologie Locale des Faisceaux Coherents et Theoremes de Lefschetz Locaux et Globaux*, A. Grothendieck with an expose by Mme. M. Raynaud.  The relevant result is Corollaire 3.6, Exp. XII, p. 153.